# ElasticsearchRepository search by specific field

Tags: search, elasticsearch, jhipster

I need besides what query comes in, I look on the "entorno" field of my entity "Terreno0101".
I get to my api rest the value of environment.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/_search/terreno-0101-s",
    method = RequestMethod.GET,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public ResponseEntity<List<Terreno0101DTO>> searchTerreno0101S(@RequestParam Map<String,String> requestParams, Pageable pageable)
    throws URISyntaxException {
    String query = requestParams.get("query");
    String entorno = requestParams.get("entorno");
    log.debug("REST request to search for a page of Terreno0101S for query {}", query);
    Page<Terreno0101> page = terreno0101Service.search(requestParams.get("query"), pageable);
    HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generateSearchPaginationHttpHeaders(query, page, "/api/_search/terreno-0101-s");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(terreno0101Mapper.terreno0101SToTerreno0101DTOs(page.getContent()), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

The Service

```
 @Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Page<Terreno0101> search(String query, Pageable pageable) {
    log.debug("Request to search for a page of Terreno0101S for query {}", query);
    return terreno0101SearchRepository.search(queryStringQuery(query), pageable);
}
```

The Repository

```
public interface Terreno0101SearchRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Terreno0101, Long> {
```

}

But not as add to my service and / or repository, for only look for those that meet the condition that query and also the "entorno" is the field that gets me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the QueryBuilders API to construct a query for this:

```
return terreno0101SearchRepository.search(QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
    .must(queryStringQuery(query)).must(matchQuery("entorno", entorno)));
```

You can also construct the same kind of query using the [@Query annotation.](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/1.0.0.M1/reference/html/elasticsearch.repositories.html#elasticsearch.query-methods.at-query)

You can even include the filtering as part of the queryStringQuery:

```
"entorno:value searchString"
```